# Не скрывать элементы меню после выбора

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, menu, android-toolbar

У меня в приложении есть небольшое меню с группой чекбоксов:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:onClick="btnSolveClick"
        android:title="Вычислить"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:onClick="btnHistoryClick"
        android:title="История"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_features"
        android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_closure"
            android:title="Замыкания"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_keys"
            android:title="Ключи"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        ...
    </group>
</menu>
```

Я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы после выбора элемента из группы меню не закрывалось автоматически

[image: меню]

Код, связанный с меню в MainActivity:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        this.menu = menu
        menu.forEach { it.isChecked = true }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        //todo тут запоминаем item.itemId
        item.isChecked = !item.isChecked
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Не думаю, что это возможно сделать. Если это не очень надо - лучше не тратить время. Если очень надо - откажитесь от меню и сделайте иначе. Диалогом с собственной разметкой, обработками нажатий и прочего. Меню кастомизировать дико сложно и, обычно, невозможно.

Comment: поддержу комментатора выше. когда то тоже была похожая задача, убил 2 дня, плюнул и сделал кастомное меню с анимацией. Тулбар в Андроиде вообще очень капризная вещь. либо юзай как из коробки либо лучше вообще не юзать)